# Is a canonical projection always continuous in the quotient topological space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

I'm solving some exercises on quotient topology, and I wonder if a canonical surjection is always continuous.

> Let $\pi: (X,\tau_X)\to (X/_\sim,\tau_\sim)$ be a canonical surjection.

I think $\pi$ is continuous, because of the following.

Let $U\in \tau_\sim$ then by definition of $\tau_\sim := \{ V\in X/_\sim: \pi^{-1}(V)\in \tau_X\}$ the inverse $\pi^{-1}(U)\in \tau_X$ which would imply $\pi$ to be continuous.

Is this true?

Comment: As you say, to be an open set in $X/\!\sim$ is precisely to be a set whose preimage in $X$ is open. It would be pretty awful if $\pi$ were not continuous. In fact you can think of the quotient topology as being the strongest (I hope I'm using the right word; I always mix them up) topology on $X/\!\sim$ such that $\pi$ is continuous. It also has a very attractive universal property.

Comment: In fact the quotient topology is defined to be the finest topology on $X/\!\sim$ that makes $\pi$ continuous.

Comment: More generally, $f:X\to Y$ is any map from a space $(X,\tau)$ to a set $Y$, we can equip $Y$ with the topology $\{V\subseteq Y\mid f^{-1}(V)\in\tau\}$. This topology makes $f$ continuous, and among all topologies on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous, it is the finest, which follows directly from the definition.

Comment: The topology mentioned in Stefan Hamcke comment is also called [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology). (Although these comments are probably of much grater generality for what the OP needs here, they still might be worth mentioning.)